# ESP32 BLE service not visible to Node-RED

Tags: bluetooth, esp32, ble

I've been trying to host a BLE-server on my ESP32 with a custom service. I'm trying to read the service data in NodeRED, but the service IDs and custom characteristics don't show up in NodeRED whenever I import the scan results of my BLE input node in NodeRED.
The device and service both show up fine on Android using NRFtool:

[image]

However, in NodeRED, the device shows up and connects just fine, but none of the characterestics are displayed at NodeRED's end:

[image]

[image]

I'm using NodeRED version 1.2.9 with the [Generic BLE node](https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-contrib-generic-ble). And the ESP32 sample i'm using can be found [here](https://github.com/LiveSparks/ESP32_BLE_Examples/blob/master/BLE_potentiometer/BLE_potentiometer.ino).

I've also tried the BLE server examples included with the BLEDevice library with similar issues.
In addition to this: I'm not sure if this is just a typo in the node's error message, or if it's a typo in the node itself, but all mentions of the type "topic" are displayed as "tpoic" in NodeRED's debug log. Though i doubt this affects the functionality of the node in any way. Nowhere in my flow is there a mention of the keyword "tpoic".

[image]

Any suggestions as to how i could make my services show up in NodeRED would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out BlueZ on linux no longer supports ESP32 BLE devices. I tried the same code on a bluefruit M0 and it worked just fine.